# Stuck underwater in Burenia?

Tags: metroid-dread

I've just gotten the Space Jump and the next accessible area is in Burenia. This lead me down underwater where I hit the floor but I think I'm stuck.

[image: map]

Looking around, there's big open areas where there are some water enemies, then to the far right, there's a little cove with what appears to be a power bomb block. But I don't see where else to go.

[image: interesting area]

I can't jump high enough to get anywhere since I don't yet have the Gravity Suit. None of my other weapons seem to be of help here.

Where do I go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's one of those exploding blobs up above in that room. You have to make use of your Diffusion Beam (your charged shot) to damage and make it explode.

[image: blob]

Destroying it will open a path from the previous room.